# How to add confirmation box to Save button in Pimcore/EXTJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, handler, pimcore

I have a generic Split button defined like:

```
this.toolbarButtons.publish = new Ext.SplitButton({
            text: t('save_and_publish'),
            iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save_white',
            cls: 'pimcore_save_button',
            scale: 'medium',
            handler: this.publish.bind(this),
            menu: [{
                text: t('save_pubish_close'),
                iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save',
                handler: this.publishClose.bind(this)
            },
            {
                text: t('save_only_new_version'),
                iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save',
                handler: this.save.bind(this, 'version'),
                hidden: !this.isAllowed('save') || !this.data.general.o_published
            }
            ]
        });
```

What I need to happen is - when user clicks the Publish button a confirm box appears which collects yes/no click.
I have a AJAX call on the yes/no click to execute/prevent user notification of the publish action.

I have tried something like this:

```
this.toolbarButtons.publish = new Ext.SplitButton({
            text: t('save_and_publish'),
            iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save_white',
            cls: 'pimcore_save_button',
            scale: 'medium',
            listeners: {
                click: function() {
                    Ext.MessageBox.confirm(
                        'Confirm', 'Notify related users?', callbackFunction);
                    function callbackFunction(btn) {
                        if(btn == 'yes') {
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: Routing.generate('save_phrase_and_notify'),
                                jsonData: {
                                    notifyFlag: JSON.stringify(true),
                                    phraseId: JSON.stringify(phraseId),
                                },
                                method: 'POST',
                                success: (response) => {
                                     button.up('window').close();
                                },
                                failure: () => {
                                    Ext.MessageBox.alert(
                                        t('Sum Tim Wong'),
                                    );
                                },
                            });

                        } else {
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: Routing.generate('save_phrase_and_notify'),
                                jsonData: {
                                    notifyFlag: JSON.stringify(false),
                                    phraseId: JSON.stringify(phraseId),
                                },
                                method: 'POST',
                                success: (response) => {
                                    button.up('window').close();
                                },
                                failure: () => {
                                    Ext.MessageBox.alert(
                                        t('Sum Tim Wong 2'),
                                    );
                                },
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            handler: this.publish.bind(this),
            menu: [{
                text: t('save_pubish_close'),
                iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save',
                handler: this.publishClose.bind(this)
            },
                {
                    text: t('save_only_new_version'),
                    iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_save',
                    handler: this.save.bind(this, 'version'),
                    hidden: !this.isAllowed('save') || !this.data.general.o_published
                }
            ],
        });
```

This confirm box work but I need to prevent the handler( *handler: this.publish.bind(this)*) from executing until the yes/no is clicked by the user. Currently the confirm box appears but the handler runs anyways, which redirects to a overview page.

How do I prevent the handler from running until yes/no is clicked? Ultimately how can I move the handler bind action in the AJAX success function?

Comment: Why don't you put this entire logic with `MessageBox` to the handler? Why do you need a `click` listener anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did put the logic in the handler and it works as far as confirm box, but my 'this.publish.bind(this)' call returned an error. I am assuming I have a scope problem or maybe I need to pass the 'this' inside the handler function somehow. Not sure what the scope of 'this' is in this case...